# How to Define main DIV if one of it childs consist of some text? Using c# & selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

The main DIV consist of text in one of it's childs & consist of button i need to click if text is present. How can i define the main div to continue work with this if one of it's childs strictly consist of text i need?

Structure seems like:

```
<Div class="Green"> (Main Div i mentioned in description)
<Div class="Yel">
<Div class="Ora">
<Div class="Pur">
<span>text must be present</span>
```

I need to define main div , to proceed with this by findelement. then.

Comment: why you don't close div element <div> </div> ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below.

```
Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='Green' and //span[normalize-space(.)='137']]//button[@class='needed_item']")).Click()
```

or

```
Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[normalize-space(.)='137']/ancestor::div[@class='Green']//button[@class='needed_item']")).Click()
```

This xpath will first find the main div which have a span with `137` text. And then click on the button which have the class `needed_item`. Considered the below structure for the xpath.

```
<div @understand='main_div' @class='Green'>
    <div @understand='child_div1'></div>
    <div @understand='child_div2'>
        <span @understand='target_span'> 137 </span>
    </div>
    <div @understand='child_div3></div>
    <div @understand='div with button'>
        <button @class='needed_item'>Target Button</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Let me know if there is any change in the structure.